# A clarification on a residue problem

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, residue-calculus

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem:

[image]

I do not see how one concludes that the residue is $\frac{e^{-t}}{2i}$. We still don't have our Laurent expansion around $i$... 
What I was inclined to do was: expand the exponential around $z=i$ and then try to get the Laurent Series from there, but it gets very ugly very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\operatorname{Res}_{z=i}f(z)=\lim_{z\to i}\;(z-i)f(z)=\lim_{z\to i}\;(z-i)\left[\frac{e^{itz}}{2i(z-i)}-\frac{e^{itz}}{2i(z+i)}\right]=\lim_{z\to i}\;\frac{e^{itz}}{2i}=\frac{e^{-t}}{2i}
$$

Comment: Aren't you assuming that you already know that $i$ is an order-1 pole?

Comment: Only if the singularity is a pole of degree one or removable

Comment: $i$ is a simple pole.

Comment: How do you know that in advance? (without writing the expansion)

Comment: using the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_(complex_analysis)) and the expression you gave for $f(z)$.

Comment: @Soap from the equation you wrote, it is already evident that i and -i are simple poles. You have written out the equation in a way which shows that that equation goes to infinity for either of those inputs and since the denominators are only to the first power, you know they can't be higher order poles.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple singularities, you can evaluate each separately, and sum them.

$\oint_\gamma \frac {f(z)}{z-a} \ dz = 2\pi i f(a)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{e^{itz}}{z^2+1}=\frac{e^{itz}}{(z+i)(z-i)}$$ which you can see has simple poles if we plug in $i$ or $-i$ for $z$.

The residue can then be obtained by the  general formula:

$$\text{Res}_{z=c}f(z)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to c}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}[(z-c)f(z)]$$ where $n$ is the order of the pole.